# Using Facebook Graph API Is it possible to suppress the news-feed publishing when creating an event for a page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

If a person on Facebook has liked a page that you create a bunch of events for, it can spam their newsfeed. Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the news feed item right after the event has been created.  But this will delete it from the news feed of everyone who likes your page.

Answer (score 0):

you can mark the event privacy as 'private' then it will not display in news feed